# Can't install anything. Getting error - Depends python <2.8 but 3.6.1-1 is to be installed. Please help!

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, python, dependencies

So I have this very frustrating problem(Ubuntu 16.04), whenever I try to install ANYTHING via apt-get I get error saying unmet dependencies. But it says that it depends python <2.8 but 3.6.1-1 is to be installed. I don't get this because I already have python 2.7.12. 
The message looks like this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnl-3-dev : Depends: libnl-3-200 (= 3.2.27-1ubuntu0.16.04.1) but 3.2.27-1 is to be installed
 python-libxml2 : Depends: python (< 2.8) but 3.6.1-1 is to be installed
 python-lzma : Depends: python (< 2.8) but 3.6.1-1 is to be installed
           Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-pycurl : Depends: python (< 2.8) but 3.6.1-1 is to be installed
             Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-rpm : Depends: python (< 2.8) but 3.6.1-1 is to be installed
          Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-sqlite : Depends: python (< 2.8) but 3.6.1-1 is to be installed
 python-sqlitecachec : Depends: python (< 2.8) but 3.6.1-1 is to be installed
 python-talloc : Depends: python (< 2.8) but 3.6.1-1 is to be installed
 python-urlgrabber : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                 Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 virtualbox : Depends: python (< 2.8) but 3.6.1-1 is to be installed
          Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 yum : Depends: python (< 2.8) but 3.6.1-1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Please help me if you can, I have been struggling with this problem for awhile.
Thanks in advance!

Update: When I run: apt-cache policy python:

```
python:
  Installed: 3.6.1-1
  Candidate: 3.6.1-1
  Version table:
 *** 3.6.1-1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.7.11-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Update: reinstalling python does not help as well, also apt-get -f install does not help, I really don't know what to do?

Comment: It sounds to me like you have a broken system - in 16.04, the Python package is actually still Python 2, while python3 is its own Python3 package.  Do you have any odd PPAs installed or anything?

Comment: I'm sorry but I am still very new to this, I really don't know, how can I check for this PPAs?

Comment: Run `apt-cache policy python`.  Copy-paste the output into your question as an edit.

Comment: You could try the suggested command:  `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: I have tried that, but I get the same message :(

Answer (score 0):

## I finally did it!

Thanks to everybody who helped me along the way, the solution was extremely simple, I just needed to update ubuntu (I clicked on the red-white icon in top right corner) and that's it!
I hope this helps other users as well.